# NodeJS admin backend authentication strategy

Tags: node.js, express

I built a simple e-commerce site for a customer based in `NodeJS/Express3/MongoDB` and I have some doubts about what kind of authentication strategy to implement for the backend of the site.

I have little to no knowledge in `authentication/authorization` and I'm a little bit lost, so I'll appreciate if you help me clear the fog a little.

Only one person, the owner is going to access it. I implemented **HTTP Simple authentication** in the past, but as long as I know, the credentials are sent in plain text. I would need to implement HTTPS but I'm trying to avoid that.

I though about `OAuth2` but it seems overkill for a single login.

Maybe Digest fits my needs. It doesn't send the credentials in plain text as long as I know.

I also found this library that look very well:

```
http://passportjs.org/
```

What do you recommend for this scenario?

Comment: if it is simple HTTP Basic/Digest authentication http-auth should also do fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Passport with local strategy is good enough.
Use [HTTPS](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html) is always good, and not hard in Node.js.

Read [The Web Application Hacker's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118026470) if you wanna go deeper.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use HTTP Basic or Digest authentication with HTTPS, you can do that using [http-auth](https://github.com/http-auth/http-auth) module.

```
// HTTPS module
var https = require('https');

// File system module.
var fs = require('fs');

// Authentication module.
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area.",
    file: __dirname + "/../data/users.htpasswd" // gevorg:gpass, Sarah:testpass ...
});

// HTTPS server options.
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/../data/server.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/../data/server.crt")
};

// Starting server.
https.createServer(basic, options, function (req, res) {
    res.end("Welcome to private area - " + req.user + "!");
}).listen(1337);
```